# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when importing into rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write jquery inside a rails application. I've imported jquery into the app, but it wasn't recognizing the $. At the top of the .js file I"m working in I imported:

```js
import $ from 'jquery'
window.$ = $
```

but I get the unexpected identifier error. The error points to the import line.

Comment: Who is giving you the error? The browser or something in Rails?

Comment: the browser, but only in the console log, it's not breaking anything else.

Comment: I think you should read about add jquery into rails app, there are plenty tutorials out there depending on your installed ruby/rails version

Answer (score 0):

Rails is not using webpack or other module-aware and es6-aware build tools (until webpacker).

If you want to use modules, either

- use webpacker (which needs a specific directory structure), or
- use a UMD-like module (the ones that declare dependencies in a way that's compatible with require.js, commonjs and globals) and browserify.

Read more on UMD modules here https://dontkry.com/posts/code/browserify-and-the-universal-module-definition.html

On webpacker, for instance here https://medium.com/statuscode/introducing-webpacker-7136d66cddfb